# Pushing objects into an array from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

my server side code

```
router.put('/api/user1', function(request, response){

Model.findById(request.body._id, function(err, user){
    console.log(request.body);
    if(err){
        response.status(404).send(err);
    }
    else {
        user.update(
                {"_id": user._id }, 
                { '$push':
                        { "feed": {"status":request.body.status, "comments":request.body.comments}  }})
    }
        })
});
```

my client side code

```
vm.statusUpdateUser = function(user,status,comments){
            console.log(status);
            var payload = {_id: user._id, status: status, comments:comments }

            if(user){
                $http.put('/api/user1', payload).then(function(response){
                    console.log('status details send'+ user.feed.status);
                    vm.getUsers();

                        })
                    }
                }
```

here is my mongoose model

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
},
diameter: {
    type:  String, 
    required: true,

},
atno: {
    type:  Date,
    default : Date.now 

},
holder: {
    type:  Date, 

},
toolType: {
    type:  String, 
    required: true 
},
feed:[{
    status: {
        type: String
                },
    comments: {
        type: String
    },
    posted_date: {
        type: Date,
        default : Date.now

    }
}]
});
```

I am trying to push status and comments into my feed array
but it not going through, please help with this issue.
the get put delete post all working fine but adding a key value pair into an array is not working for me

any idea guys??

Comment: Is `Model` the name of the user model that uses the `UsersSchema`?

Comment: Hi rpserverbox; I have to say that your question needs a bit more context. When you say it is not going through, can you say exactly what that means: do you get errors back? Or does it proceed without errors, but the data is unchanged?

Comment: I will post my whole code here may be that can help you understand my problem. I feel I am really bad at explaining things .. I am not from a coding background. when I checked the browser network the status is shown as pending.. i have hosted this app online ... http://23.251.146.26:8000. i hope this will probably help you understand my issues... the button status change is suppose to add status and comments in an feed array. which is not happening

Comment: is `Model` the name of your user model in `Model.findById(request.body._id, function(err, user){`

Comment: yes Model is the name of the user model referring my model.js file
         var Model = require('./models/models.js');